# Subclassing QGraphicsItem prevents me from being able to use itemAt() on a QGraphicsScene/View

Tags: c++, qt

I've subclassed QGraphicsItem into my own custom class, Hexagon. When I try to use a function such as `QGraphicsView::itemAt`, or `QGraphicsScene::itemAt`, it won't return any of my `Hexagon` objects because the function instead looks for `QGraphicsItems`.
How can I tell it to look for `Hexagon` objects instead? Or do I need to change something in my `Hexagon` class? Or even re-implement `itemAt()`?

Currently, I'm also subclassing `QGraphicsView`, particlarly `mousePressedEvent` to get some info about the `Hexagon` object that is clicked on.

```
void LatticeView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Hexagon *hexagon = itemAt(event->pos());
    ...
}
```

But when I try to compile, I get the following error:

> invalid conversion from 'QGraphicsItem*' to 'Hexagon*'

What I want is to be able to get the `Hexagon` object that is clicked on so that I can access some variables I've defined in the `Hexagon` class that are not implicit in the `QGraphicsItem` class.

Comment: what do you mean "won't return any of my Hexagon objects"?  Sounds like you just need to cast back and forth from QGraphicsItem* to Hexagon*.

Comment: Have you implemented boundingRect()?

Comment: I mean that "itemAt()" has a return type of QGraphicsItem, so if I call itemAt() -- for example, in the QGraphicsItem's mousePressedEvent function -- it doesn't return my Hexagon objects because the return type is QGraphicsItem. You're right, I probably do need to just cast back and forth between QGraphicsItem and Hexagon, but I don't know how or where I'd do that. I had thought it would be enough if I just inherited QGraphicsItem in my Hexagon class, but obviously it's not. Thanks!

Comment: Arnold, yes, I have implemented it. Pretty sure it's not the issue.

Comment: Shoot, I meant (in my above comment) ***for example, in the QGraphicsScene's/View's mousePressedEvent function.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your issue. Is `itemAt()` returning null or a value?

Comment: This is what I get: "error: invalid conversion from 'QGraphicsItem*' to 'Hexagon*'. I'll edit my question to provide additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get this to work, you would need to cast the pointer before assigning it to a pointer variable of another type..

```
Hexagon *hexagon = (Hexagon*)itemAt(event->pos());
```

But there is danger here since `itemAt()` may return `NULL` or the item may not be a `Hexagon` item.

In fact, you should use the C++ style cast like this:

```
Hexagon *hexagon = dynamic_cast<Hexagon*>(itemAt(event->pos()));
if (hexagon != NULL)
{
   hexagon->hexagonMethod();
}
```

This will require Run-time type information to be available through your compiler.

There is also a `QGraphicsItem` function available called [type()](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#type) which will allow you to use `qgraphicsitem_cast()` but that requires a little extra work involving defining an `enum`.

One additional thing to watch out for. Depending on how your scene and items are consuming mouse events, you may not always see your override of `mousePressEvent()` get called when you expect it to since the mouse event may never get up to the view if it is consumed by something in the scene.

Comment: Brilliant. That makes sense. Thank you so much! I used your second bit of code, and it works perfectly. Would you mind saying a bit more about what you said, "This will require Run-time type information to be available through your compiler"? I don't quite understand. If it matters, I'm using Qt Creator.

Comment: `dynamic_cast` requires run-time type information (RTTI) which is provided by the compiler and is sometimes not enabled by default. This shouldn't be a concern with QtCreator and g++. You can read some more about it all here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting