# Qt add extended QGraphicsItem to scene

Tags: c++, qt

I have created a class `Atom` that extends the Qt class `QGraphicsItem` like this:

```
Atom::Atom(qreal rad, qreal mass, int element, int state) : QGraphicsItem()
{
    // Initialization code
}
void Atom::changeState(int newState)
{
    // Code...
}
```

Then, I add my atom to the scene like this:

```
Atom *a=new Atom(rad,mass,element,state);
a->setPos(pos);
scene->addItem(a);
```

However, Qt converts my Atom class to a QGraphicsItem class. Now, when I call `scene->items()`, I get a QList of QGraphicsItems, which do not have the properties and methods of my Atom class.

So, I am asking the question: How would I go about getting a list of the Atoms that I have added to my QGraphicsScene?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Your items are not converted to anything. They are still of your custom type. In C++, all objects of a derived class are also of class they derive from. Nothing is converted so nothing is lost.

Do a `dynamic_cast<Atom*>(item)` and you will get your item back.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between: `dynamic_cast<Atom*>(item)` vs `((Atom*)item)`?

Comment: @Joel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28002/regular-cast-vs-static-cast-vs-dynamic-cast

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to cast the QGraphicsItems to Atoms. Please see this question for details:

[Subclassing QGraphicsItem prevents me from being able to use itemAt() on a QGraphicsScene/View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050246/qt-c-subclassing-qgraphicsitem-prevents-me-from-being-able-to-use-itemat)